# non-static initialization of a flexible array member

Tags: c, arrays, memory-management, struct

I'm trying to populate a struct member with an array created at runtime and get the following error:

```
error: non-static initialization of a flexible array member
             .entries = entries
                        ^
```

I have isolated the problem and reproduced it in simpler code to make it clearer:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct entry {
    char *title;
    int id;
} Entry;

typedef struct collection {
    size_t size;
    Entry entries[];
} Collection;

// This function signature may not be changed
void populate(int n, Collection *result){

    Entry entries[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        Entry entry = {
                .title = "Title",
                .id = i
        };

        entries[i] = entry;
    }

    Collection collection = {
            .size = n,
            .entries = entries
    };

    result = &collection;
}
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: You must use `malloc()` to allocate memory separately for each `Entry`. You must assume the caller has already allocated enough memory in `Collection *result`.

Comment: Use `memcpy` like [this](http://ideone.com/aTyCXX)

Comment: You have to explicitly allocate memory for title. Use malloc just as BLUEPIXY says

Comment: As written, `collection` is a local variable which is just about to end its lifetime when you assign its address to `*result`. So that function is going to store a dangling pointer into its out parameter, independent of the issue with initialising `collection`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Thanks, very helpful! I now have to determine `n` inside `populate` and consequently had to move `result = malloc(sizeof(*result) + n * sizeof(Entry))` to inside the function (before the loop), however this causes a segmentation fault error. Why?

Comment: A variable passed as an argument of a function can not be changed by that function.

Comment: footnote 93) _A function may change the values of its parameters, but these changes cannot affect the values of the
arguments. On the other hand, it is possible to pass a pointer to an object, and the function may
change the value of the object pointed to. A parameter declared to have array or function type is
adjusted to have a pointer type as described in 6.9.1._

Answer (score 1):

Actually, initialising a struct with a flexible array member is not straight forward; You will have to allocate a collection item with enough space for the entries you'd like to copy in later. So you could write something like the following:

```
Collection *coll = malloc(sizeof(Collection)+n*sizeof(Entry));
coll->size = n;
memcpy (coll->entries, entries, n*sizeof(Entry));
```

I see no other way than using such a "hand-written" `malloc`.

Note however, that if memory allocation is expected to be done in function `populate`, the signature of function `populate` cannot remain as is, because it would not allow to "return" or set a pointer to a newly allocated `Collection`-object. In this case, the signature would have to be changed either into `void populate(int n, Collection **result)` or into `Collection *populate(int n)`.

Comment: Also note that the function must return a _pointer_ to the allocated structure. Since malloc has to be used inside the function, the format `void populate(int n, Collection *result)` is no good. Preferably it should be changed to `Collection* populate(int n)`.

Comment: @Lundin: right; I think the design of the program has to be reworked in order to deal with flexible array members in a meaningful way.